# GitHub links as answers

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

Users will often answer a question with "I've done this in my project here..." and then link their GitHub repository. This is quite a frustrating experience, because it'll always be a link to the main page of the repository, and you'll always have to go digging through multiple folders before you see an answer. And especially considering that some people link huge projects and finding the relevant file let alone the relevant code can be a task.

There are many examples, but the one I last saw, which isn't as bad as it could be, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15334944/5437165). What's Stack Overflow's opinion on the matter?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There has never been a link only flag option.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think there ever was a flag that was "link only answer". I've used NAA for as long as I've been here.

Comment: I'm probably confusing something, sorry guys. I'm rarely using flags meanwhile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ link only is a widely cited reason to use NAA (if it's truly link-only).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you might be referring to the the link-only deletion reason, which appears when reviewing a post in the Low Quality Review Queue.

Comment: @ryanyuyu NAA or VLQ depending on which way the sun is pointing that day.

Comment: didn't there used to be a close reason as link only?

Comment: @Liam: Closing is for questions, not answers.  If you are referring to the questions, Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error*, and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not helpful for other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm flagging your question as LINK ONLY, because the link you provide is broken.  How ironic!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## What to Do, Part I: Comment

Always remember that you can leave comments. The following text, for example, explains the problem and sometimes prompts authors to improve their answers:

> While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

## What to Do, Part II: Edit, If Appropriate

If you [have 2000 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and can edit the post without changing its meaning, please do so. For example, if somebody posts this as an answer:

> I posted a gist with an example regex to do this: see https://gist.github.com/foo/bar

and the gist contains nothing more than the regex, you could just add the regex to the answer.

*Be careful with this approach, though!* Do not simply copy and paste other people's work, and do not do anything that gives the answer a new or totally different meaning. It's best to let the post's author do any major surgery. And it's a bad idea to do this until you have a fair amount of experience editing posts and reviewing edits to learn what is appropriate.

## What to Do, Part III: Flag It

Flag it as very low quality (VLQ)<sup>1</sup> and, assuming the author hasn't fixed it by the time we see the flag, the mods will nuke it.

## The Rationale Behind Purging these Answers

There's not much difference between these examples, which are all very common and very terrible:

1. > I just did this in my project. You can see it here: https://github.com/foo/bar
2. > I just did this in my project and wrote about it on my blog. You can see it here: https://example.com/how-to-solve-some-problem
3. > Dude! [Quora/Reddit/Facebook/whatever] has the most *amazing* post about this. You can see it here: https://example.com/start-of-another-rabbit-trail
4. > [The example you shared:] I have made a sample application with rounded listview here: [GitHub: AndroidListViewRoundedCorner](https://github.com/munnadroid/AndroidListviewRoundedCorner) [image omitted]

None of these are useful answers. Links break, [libraries go offline](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141577284765/kik-left-pad-and-npm), and, at best, link-only answers tend to send the OP down a rabbit trail. As you said, it usually takes a lot of reading and digging through other material to figure out if the link is helpful at all. This is especially true with a link to a repository, which requires the user to wade through the readme and the source to figure out:

1. Is this even relevant?
2. Is it helpful?
3. Is it *correct*?
4. Is it bug-free?
5. Is it actively maintained?
6. What are the odds that it will suddenly go offline?
7. Is the code safe or possibly malicious?
8. Is the license one I can accept?
9. How do I use it?
10. Is it performant?
11. Can I just find the answer I want, like the name of whatever method I'm looking for, without adding another dependency to my project?

In short, a link to a repo—without more—is not very helpful at all.

As explained in the help center article on [how to answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer),

> Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Refer to this classic post for more discussion of this topic: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

---

<sup>1 The VLQ flag is only available for posts from the last seven days. If the post is older than that, you can use a Not An Answer (NAA) flag if the post *really* doesn't even *try* to answer the question, or use a custom flag. NAA is only appropriate if you literally have no clue what the author is suggesting is the answer to the question. Otherwise, stick with VLQ (if available) or a custom flag.</sup>

Comment: Does this conflict with what Shog has [said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155834) on the [subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264398)? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: *What to Do, Part II: Edit, If Appropriate* - The OP should only do this once they're over 2K. In my experience it is literally **impossible** to add code to an answer, even if you make it clear that what you're adding is the OP's own code. It's hit or miss with questions but with answers you're better off not doing it if it has to go into the review queue.

Comment: @Laurel No, it's consistent with Shog's points. If the answer contains anything beyond "Use XYZ library" and a link, then it should *not* be flagged. I'm addressing the scenario in which the "answer" is "Use my repo at http://github.com/foo/bar," without explanation, context, or anything else useful.

Comment: @BSMP Very good point.

Comment: @EdCottrell What about the part where he says: *When there's no interest in [editing], or when someone else has posted a complete solution as a separate answer, I don't really see any great loss in deleting...*? I also thought that NAA was the proper flag for this thing.

Comment: @Laurel The exact line between when NAA and VLQ is appropriate is, as you probably know, a topic of much debate. But VLQ is better if the answer *is* an answer, as in "My library solves your problem: [link] [full stop]," but a lousy one. NAA is better if the post has *absolutely nothing* to indicate that it's addressing the question. For example, if the question is how to fix overlapping elements on a page, and the answer is a link to Bootstrap, well, that's not really an attempt to answer at all, so NAA is appropriate.